# How to understand the composition of automata?

Tags: composition, automata

I fail to understand any of this text on composition of I/O automata. The italic text is a passage from an essay.

***A new I/O automaton can be constructed by composing a set of compatible I/O automata.***
Is the composition to be understood like a function composition, so a sequential arrangement of automata, or can it be any network?

***A set of automata are compatible if they share no output or internal events.*** Why would sharing these events be a problem? What is the idea behind this?

***A state of the composed automaton S is a tuple of component states, and a starting state is a tuple of component starting states. The set of events of S, Events (S), is the union of the components’ sets of events. The set of output events of S, Out (S), is the union of the components’ sets of output events; the set of internal events, Int (S ), is the union of the components’ sets of internal events;*** Why is the union the way to go? Would the cartesian product not make more sense?

***and the set of input events of S, In(S), is In(S) – Out(S), all the input events of S that are not output events for some component.*** First of all this seems fishy as In(S) = In(S)-Out(S) is not a mathematical equation. I guess this is to be undersood as In(S) = Union(In(S_i))-Out(S); however why not allow Out(S) as an input?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_automaton#Composition_operation might be useful